# How to get :authority header on Nginx?

Tags: nginx

How to get **:authority** http header on Nginx?

HTTP/2 support have ":authority" header by default

I need to check $host match with $http_authority
but $http_authority is empty.

```
if ( $http_authority  ~* $host ) { return 405;  }
```

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

use $http_host or $host replace $http_authority like http.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).